Why do two paths not form the same cycle in a graph despite applying the CLRS shift formula?
A directed graph G = (V,E) on V = {1,2,3,4,5,6
Hello everyone,
I am currently working through the CLRS book (Introduction to Algorithms), and I’m having trouble verifying a formula related to cyclic paths in graphs. According to the book, two paths
⟨v0,v1​,v2​,…,vk-1​,v0​⟩ and ⟨v'0,v'1​,v'2​,…,v'k-1​,v'0​⟩ form the same cycle if there exists an integer j such that:
v'i​=v (i+j) mod k for i=0,1,…,k−1
b = [1, 2, 4, 1]
a = [4, 1, 2, 4]
k = len(a)

Iterate through possible shifts (values of j)
for j in range(0, k):
    match = True
    print(f"Testing shift j = {j}:")
    # Compare all elements after applying the shift
    for i in range(0, k):
        if b[i] != a[(i + j) % k]:
            print(f"  Mismatch at index {i}: b[{i}] = {b[i]} != a[{(i + j) % k}] = {a[(i + j) % k]}")
            match = False
            break  # No need to check further if any mismatch occurs
        else:
            print(f"  Match at index {i}: b[{i}] = {b[i]} == a[{(i + j) % k}] = {a[(i + j) % k]}")
    if match:
        print(f"For j = {j}, the paths are the same.")
        break  # Exit after finding a valid j

if not match:
    print("No valid shift found; the paths are different.")

Output:
Testing shift j = 0:
        Mismatch at index 0: b[0] = 1 != a[0] = 4
    Testing shift j = 1:
        Match at index 0: b[0] = 1 == a[1] = 1
        Match at index 1: b[1] = 2 == a[2] = 2
        Match at index 2: b[2] = 4 == a[3] = 4
        Mismatch at index 3: b[3] = 1 != a[0] = 4
   Testing shift j = 2:
        Mismatch at index 0: b[0] = 1 != a[2] = 2
   Testing shift j = 3:
        Mismatch at index 0: b[0] = 1 != a[3] = 4
   No valid shift found; the paths are different.

